# Coloring the Space widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, space

I am trying to color the Space widget. I tried using both the `android:foreground` and `android:background` attributes, but still it is displaying a transparent View.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:foreground="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: A Space is meant to be **transparent**. Why don't you use a bare View (or a TextView or an ImageView or whatever) with a colored background, instead? For dividers (which seems like the usage you're willing to achieve) I use bare Views.

Comment: why does attributes of space does not work?

Comment: "A Space is meant to be transparent." That's great for debugging, really....

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As per the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) definition:

> Space is a lightweight View subclass that may be used to create gaps between components in general purpose layouts.

They probably didn't think of "coloring an empty space".
Where "empty" means "without color", "invisible".

That's what I'd do:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
/>
```

Using a bare View as a divider is one of my 2/3 favourite tricks with bare Views.
I also use them as spacers and as "center point" in RelativeLayouts.

Comment: I know about this. I was thinking if space could be colored.

Comment: It seems it's not possible. The View will do the trick very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Paul's "view trick" but had GridLayout horizontal / vertical constraints problem (and during execution drawing stops as soon as this view is encountered).
For me (Studio 2.3.3, api 21) this worked :

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:background="@color/housetoolsBlue" />
```